# App freezes when I change EnvironmentObject value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to login my user when they click a button. When they click the button, it calls `self.auth.login()` which changes `loggedIn` to true.

When this change happens, `ContentView` is meant to reload with `HomeView()` as the body `View`. However it just crashes the app.

Here's my code:

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    @EnvironmentObject var auth: UserAuth
    var body: some View {
        if (!auth.loggedIn){
            return AnyView(LoginView())
        } else {
            return AnyView(HomeView())
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(UserAuth())
    }
}

class UserAuth: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn: Bool = false

    func login(){
        self.loggedIn = true
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var auth: UserAuth
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Image("launcher_logo").resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 100)
                    .padding(.top, 100)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.auth.login()
                    print("loggedIn: ", self.auth.loggedIn) // prints "loggedIn: true" then doesn't print again when pressed
                }) {
                    Text(String(auth.loggedIn))
                }

...
```

Any idea what the problem is?

EDIT:

If I change my `ContentView` View to just `LoginView()` then it doesn't freeze. The app works. But I wan ContentView to be dynamic based on whether the user is loggedIn or not.

EDIT2: HomeView is causing it to crash:

```
struct HomeView: View {
//    @EnvironmentObject var auth: UserAuth
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text(String("4"))
            }.onTapGesture {
//                self.auth.login()
            }
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                }
            Text("The Last Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                    Text("Profile")
                }
        }
        .font(.headline)
    }

    func goOnline(){
        print("went online")
    }
}
```

console log:

```
[Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Failed to download settings Error Domain=FIRCLSNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=404, type=2, request_id=, content_type=text/html; charset=utf-8}
2020-06-04 19:53:04.408869+1000 App[6718:4035694] Connection 5: received failure notification
2020-06-04 19:53:04.409001+1000 App[6718:4035694] Connection 5: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
2020-06-04 19:53:04.409111+1000 App[6718:4035694] Connection 5: encountered error(3:-9816)
```

Comment: Did you add `UserSettings` to your environment? (`environmentObject`). In the previews you add only one of two required Environment Objects.

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: There is no crash message. It just freezes. The last output in the console is `loggedIn: true`

Comment: If I change my `ContentView` View to just `LoginView()` then it doesn't freeze. The app works.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://gist.github.com/paulw11/9141f0b1fd05b315bf50e9ed8c231988

Comment: @Paulw11 Just realised `HomeView()` is causing it to freeze. I've added the code/error in my edit.

Comment: Your `HomeView` calls itself, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Ahhhh that must be it. Thanks. @Paulw11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `HomeView` calls itself, causing an infinite loop.